# Print / Print Preview does not match normal view for Excel worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing, formatting

I've got a certain worksheet that will not print correctly.  An image that takes up a certain amount of space in the normal view looks very different in the Print Preview view.  This is the case with different images, or after manually resizing columns, resetting page breaks, etc.  You can see the image takes up the full box in normal view, but leaves substantial white space in Print Preview below:

NORMAL VIEW:
[image: normal view]

PRINT PREVIEW:
[image: print preview]

Any idea what could cause this?  A simple workaround would be to start over with a new worksheet, but I'm curious as to what would make this happen or how to fix it going forward.

Comment: try select all cell (that contain the pics).. then print > choose:"print selection only" > preview/print.

Comment: It still shows the extra space if I do "print selection only."

Comment: I have 2 school of thoughts for this.. 1. resolve in Excel..(by trial n error of manually reducing the width of column B, then preview. adjust again, then preview again. note: I', suggesting this since you are using excel cell border as the picture frame ),  2. use Powerpnt for accurate graphic based print.( just insert a white shape box shape that have black outline. in an A4 (you paper) sized slides, then paste the picture and resize both. )

Comment: Change the view from "normal" to "page layout" and see if it helps you with changing size to get desired results.

Comment: It shows up correctly in Page Layout as well - same as in the normal view where the image takes up the entire box.

Comment: Using images inside Excel has always been a headache when trying to print it. It involves a lot of trial and error. It seems you are only using Excel to print a picture. There are many better option for working with a photo. Even non-photo software such as Word, PowerPoint, Publisher are far easier to work with photos.

Comment: Thanks Brian.  My actual spreadsheet is more complicated than just a cat picture and a box, but I needed to remove confidential/proprietary information before posting screenshots to a public forum.  In this case it does need to be in Excel.